# Rangeslider ACF in Foreach loop

Tags: foreach, advanced-custom-fields

I have a range slider in my Advanced custom fields. I want the number to be the amount of list items that it echo's out. In example, i put the range slider on 4 in ACF then it needs to echo out:

- Flywheel 1
- Flywheel 2
- Flywheel 3
- Flywheel 4

This is the code i have but it's not working, can someone please fix the code?

```
<?php 
$flywheelnumber = get_field('flywheels');
if( $flywheelnumber ) {
    echo '<form class="checklist-list">';
        echo '<ul>';
        foreach($flywheelnumber) {
            echo '<li>';
                echo ( $numbers );
            echo '</li>';
        }
        echo '</ul>';
    echo '</form>'  
}
?>
```

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

you have to use for loop. you can try these codes,

```
<?php
$flywheelnumber = get_field( 'flywheels' );
if ( $flywheelnumber ) {
    echo '<form class="checklist-list">';
    echo '<ul>';
    for ( $x = 1; $x <= count( $flywheelnumber ); $x ++ ) {
        echo '<li>' . $x . '</li>';
    }
    echo '</ul>';
    echo '</form>';
}
?>
```

Comment: Thanks! Will try tommorrow. Ill let you know if it works

Comment: Warning: count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Countable in /Users/rms01/Local Sites/nfs-no-limits-checklist/app/public/wp-content/themes/tmj/template-car.php on line 20

And Line 20 is:

    for ( $x = 1; $x <= count( $flywheelnumber ); $x ++ ) {

Comment: Just remove the ```count()``` function. I thought that ```$flywheelnumber``` will return an array.